# I'm have a variable Topic to a foreign key that produces this error: NameError: name 'Topic' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a django project where I have created a project and an app. In models.py I have two classes: Topic and Entry. When I try to runserver I get an error NameError Topic is not defined.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Lesson(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the mocel"""
        return self.text
    
class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have tried to migrate and makemigration courses the name of the app. I have rewritten the code and checked for indentation. I'm following the code in a text called Python Crash Course to the letter. At one point my code was working but now I'm getting NameError: name 'Topic' is not defined. But when I do python manage.py runserver 8000 I keep getting the error.

Comment: No, `Lesson` and `Entry`.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the definition of the `Topic`-model?

If it is in the same file, but later, you can either put it before the definition of `Entry`, or define the field `topic` like this: `topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` where you just use the name, rather than referencing the model directly.

If it is in another file, you forgot to import it.

If you meant to reference the `Lesson` model, you need to do so:
`topic = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. You just accidentally named the class 'Lesson' and not 'Topic'. If you want to have foreign key to 'Topic' then either rename your class to class Topic:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
```

or simply just correct:

```
topic = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I hope this helps.